# Winamp 5.6 and Firefox 4 problem

Tags: firefox, freeze, winamp

I am usng winamp 5.6 on Windows 7, which works without a problem. However if I have Firefox 4 open (no addons) and skip to a different song in aplaylist, or if it changes to the next song after finishing the previous, Firefox will lockup for around 2 minutes or sometimes longer.

How can I troubleshoot this problem, and see if the fault lies with Firefox or Winamp?

Comment: are you using any addon like foxytunes or foxamp which would allow your browser to interact with your winamp ?

Comment: No, no addons at all.

Answer (score 0):

Uninstall Winamp and Firefox.

Install [VLC Media Player](http://www.videolan.org/vlc/) and [Google Chrome](http://www.google.com/chrome/). I used to use Winamp for all my media playing needs, but then version 4 came along, and then 5, and between the two of them, I was turned away by bloat and bugs. I've switched to VLC and never looked back.

As for browsers, I've found that Internet Explorer 9 is actually pretty good, but I use Chromium when in Linux, and Dolphin Browser HD on my Android devices.

Comment: Well... this is a REALLY dirty workaround... if we can even call it a workaround. For the Winamp VS VLC, +. If you don't like VLC, you can even try Foobar. (Very nice player.) But Firefox... I don't see a point in switching down the browser too. FF will be fine.

Comment: Here's another thought. Open your task manager, and on the tab with CPU and memory usage, click resource monitor. Start Winamp and FireFox, then reproduce the offending behavior. Watch the resource monitor for HDD usage, CPU usage, and memory usage of the two processes. You may discover a pattern that will help in tracking this down. Post anything interesting or repeatable so we can take a look at what is going on.